# Electron app not detecting updates from GitHub using electron-updater

Tags: electron, auto-update

I'm developing an Electron application, and I'm trying to implement automatic updates using the electron-updater package with GitHub as the provider. However, my Electron app is not detecting updates from GitHub.

I have the following code in my index.js file:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');

autoUpdater.autoDownload = true;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
  console.log('autoUpdater checking');
});

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  console.log('Update found!');
  autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();
});

autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  console.log('No Update found');
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  console.log('Update Downloaded!');
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (info) => {
  console.log(info);
});
```

And my package.json includes the necessary dependencies and configuration:

```
{
  "name": "electron-test",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "This is my Electron app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/my_profile_name/my-repo-name",
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "releaseType": "release"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.weeeeb.app",
    "productName": "ABC ABC",
    "mac": {
      "category": "my.app.category",
      "target": "dmg"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

I have already created a new release on GitHub and tagged it with the same version specified in the package.json. Also, I changed the filename spaces to dashes as required by Electron. However, when I run my Electron app, it doesn't detect any updates from GitHub, and I don't see any related console log messages.

What could be the possible reasons for my Electron app not detecting updates from GitHub? Am I missing any additional configuration or making any mistakes in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!